# how to set asp.net image control width and height property

Tags: image, set, height, width

i am using asp.net and c# 
i want to set image height and width property using c# code , i can do it , but the value will be set as an inline style 
like this :

```
<img id="image1" style="height:220px;width:800px;border-width:0px;">
```

but i want something like this

```
<img id="image1" width="800" height="220">
```

i use this code , but it render like css code :(

```
  image1.Width = 800;
  image1.Height =220;
```

is there any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Just define it as attribute:

```
image1.Attributes.Add("width", "800");
image1.Attributes.Add("height", "220");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  Width="800" Height="220" />
```

instead of

```
<img id="image1" width="800" height="220">
```

it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `Unit.Pixel()` method. So in your case:

```
image1.Width = Unit.Pixel(800);
image1.Height = Unit.Pixel(220);
```